# No visible @interface, adding parameter to initWithFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a ViewController (VCViewController) with this code in it:

```
touchView = [[VCTouchView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 320, 480} andTheCameraController:self];
```

in the UIView (VCTouchView) though I have:

```
(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTheCameraController:(VCViewController*)cameraController
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Basically I have a ViewController which I want to add an overlay.  On this overlay will be a button for the user to press that will take a photo.  Quite simple requirement, yet I cannot understand why it can't see the parameter called andTheCameraController?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Please share actual code and not screenshots of your code. Also please include your `@interface` code for `VCTouchView`

Comment: Please don't do screenshots of code. It's much better to just copy paste the code into the question. Also, can you show the code in VCTouchView.h.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, will do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the new method to your `VCTouchView.h` file?

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTheCameraController:(VCViewController *)cameraController;
```

Comment: Ah. Yes good point.... doh..  I think I forgot to do it because normally you don't declare initWithFrame.  So I added the parameter and then didn't declare the whole method.

Comment: Yes, -initWithFrame: is already declared in the superclass header (UIView.h), so you don't need to declare it. Please accept this answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks!